# High memory usage with Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, memory-management

```
public static void Main()
{
    int size = 250000;
    var a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a[i]);
}
```

When I tested the above code with CLRProfiler, it told me that the code allocates roughly    40 MB. Around 20 MB is allocated to `String`, 9 MB to `Char[]`, 5 MB to `StringBuilder` and 3 MB to `Int32`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int size = 250000;
    var a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("0");
}
```

This one allocates around 5 MB. 4 MB is allocated to `Char[]`.

The only thing I get is that array `a` should require 1 MB (250,000 * 4).

Why is there such a massive difference ? Why are all those objects required for the first code and how do I reduce the memory allocation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely the memory increase is because of the complexity involved in parsing the format string.

In your first case, it has to parse the format string, get a localized string representing the integer and put it in the right place of the format string.

In your second case you are outputting just a single value, and even more so, a plain string. It is very trivial in comparison.

If you are interested in what goes on under the covers you can use [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) and have a look at the `WriteLine` overloads.

Comment: And probably the constant string "0" is interned so there exists only one instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of runtime-specific question.
My guess would be that first code uses so much memory because of conversion of `int` to `String`, which has to be made in order to format string for `Console.WriteLine` correctly.