# Why GC.GetTotalMemory returns different results?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

When I try this code

```
public static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total bytes : " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

                Console.WriteLine("Total bytes : " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

                Console.WriteLine("Total bytes : " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

I get these results

[image]

Why there is a difference between first and rest of the results?

Comment: Coz its *best available [**approximation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) of the number of bytes*

Comment: Also, there are always some background threads running which will cause slight fluctuations in allocated memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason for this would be that your code is translated to something like this:

```
int totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
string s = "Total bytes : " + totalMemory;
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

On the second line of the above code, the `String` class is initialized, if it hasn't been already. That means  its static fields are initialized and its static constructor is called (if it has any). Then the `Concat()` method is called, and all classes required during its run are initialized too.

And on the third line the `Console` class is initialized, if it hasn't been already. Then of course all the classes used during the execution of `WriteLine()` too.

All the static fields require some memory, so it males sense that when you call `GC.GetTotalMemory()` for the second time, you get a somewhat higher number.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but `Console.WriteLine` is consuming memory... That's becaues after one call to it memory value doesn't change.

Have look to this answer help you to find out the thing in more detail : [High memory usage with Console.WriteLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430380/high-memory-usage-with-console-writeline)